# Density of $d$ for which a generalized Pell equation has a solution

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-equations

For how many $0 < d \leq D$ is there an integer solution to

$$x^2-dy^2 = -n$$

for $n > 1$? I have circumstantial reason to believe it might be $\sim D^{\frac{1}{2}}$ but I'd be interested in any upper bound that is $o(D)$.

Comment: You can get the upper bound $O(D/ ( \log D)^{1/2})$ by a fairly standard argument similar to counting the number of integers which are sum of two squares.

Comment: I severely doubt that one gets $D^{1/2}$ for this problem. For the negative Pell equation ($n=1$) it is a famous conjecture that the above upper bound I state is of the correct order of magnitude. I don't see why general $n$ should be any different.

Comment: So there's a conjecture of Granville that says that the number of squarefree $d \leq D$ for which $dy^2 = f(x)$ has a solution is $D^{\frac{1}{\deg f}}$, but I'd totally believe that it's not $D^{\frac{1}{2}}$. However, I do think it might be $D^{1-\epsilon}$ for $\epsilon > 0$ because of some computational work that shows that $\sum_{d \colon \exists\text{ an integral solution}} \frac{1}{d}$ converges.

Comment: Oops to clarify - the conjecture of Granville (Conjecture 1 of https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/28e7/61984b63117ed17b887f7d1206e53ee8abdd.pdf) was made only for $dy^2 = f(x)$ where the degree of $f$ was at least $3$, but I totally believe that things are different for quadratic $f$.

Comment: Edit to my first comment: the computational work doesn't show that the sum converges of course, but it looks very much like it does :P

Comment: @DanielLoughran I see that there's a conjecture of Stevenhagen that predicts the bounds you gave for *rational* solutions to the negative Pell equation (and some progress due to Fouvry and Klümers: https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v172-n3-p13-p.pdf). However, couldn't the situation be quite different for integral solutions? At least, computationally, the sum I mentioned seems to converge for the negative Pell equation if we look at $d$ for which there exists an integral solution but definitely doesn't converge in the rational case.

Comment: Stevenhagen's conjecture is definitely about integral solutions and not rationals solutions; the case of rational solutions is very classical and due to Landau and independently Ramanujan. Please read the introduction of this paper again more carefully.

Comment: My bad, you're totally right!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To expand on Dan's answer, for general $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ the equation

$$\displaystyle x^2 - dy^2 = n$$

is soluble in integers $x,y$ only if the quadratic form

$$\displaystyle q_{d,n}(x,y,z) = x^2 - dy^2 - nz^2$$

is everywhere locally soluble, i.e., it is soluble over $\mathbb{R}$ and over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for every prime $p$. That it is soluble over $\mathbb{R}$ is clear, since we assumed that $d > 0$ so the ternary quadratic form $q_{d,n}$ is guaranteed to be indefinite.

Notice that we may assume that $d,n$ are both square-free, since we can absorb any square factors into the variables. For simplicity we shall assume that $\gcd(d,n) = 1$.

It is a well-known theorem of Legendre that for a diagonal ternary quadratic form $q_{d,n}$ is soluble over all primes $p$ if and only if the congruences

$$\displaystyle \begin{cases}  v^2 \equiv n \pmod{d} \\ v^2 \equiv d \pmod{n} \end{cases}$$

are both soluble. The second condition is equivalent to requiring that every prime factor of $d$ splits over (the ring of integers of) the quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$, and the number of such $d \leq X$ satisfying this condition is $\sim c_n X(\log X)^{-1/2}$ for some $c_n > 0$. The first condition is saying that $d \equiv \square \pmod{p}$ for every prime $p | n$ (and also possibly accounting for $-1$ when $n$ is negative), so only introduces a multiplicative factor depending only on $n$. We thus get an upper bound of $O_n(X(\log X)^{-1/2})$.

In principle the method of Fouvry-Kluners can be used in general to produce a lower bound of the same order of magnitude I believe.

Answer (score 6):

(Upgrading comments to answer.)

Counting the number of $D$ for which the equation has a *rational solution* is a fairly classical problem. This is asymptotic to $c_nD/(\log D)^{1/2}$ for some $c_n > 0$. The case $n=1$ is a result due to Landau and Ramanujan independently:

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Landau-RamanujanConstant.html

The case of general $n$ follows a similar method and is due to Landau I believe.

This in particular gives the upper number $O(D/(\log D)^{1/2})$ for the number which have an *integral solution*.

In fact, at least for $n=1$, one expects that a positive proportion of those with a rational solution have an integral solution, so the count for integral solutions is conjecturally asymptotic to some constant times $D/(\log D)^{1/2}$. This conjecture is due Stevenhagen, who also gave a precise formula for the constant, and in fact a correct of magnitude result is a famous theorem of Fouvry and Klüners.

I don't see why the case of general $n$ should be any different, so your expectation of $D^{1/2}$ is almost certainly false.

Answer (score 6):

Recently Koymans and Pagano have established an asymptotic formula in this setting: $n$ a prime with $n$ congruent to $3$ modulo $4$, within the family of $d$ where $n$ ramifies in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ and with $d$ congruent $3$ modulo $4$ (in general they consider the principal quadratic form), see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.14157.pdf. They also improve upper and lower bounds of Fouvry and Kluners for $n=1$.